# Trouble scraping table with DOMXPath

Tags: php, domxpath

I have a table I'm trying to scrape that looks like this:

```
<table id="thisTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="value1"></td>
        <td class="value2"></td>
        <td class="value3"></td>
        <td class="value4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="value5"></td>
        <td class="value6"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my DOMXPath that looks like this (so far):

```
$htmlDoc = new DomDocument();
@$htmlDoc->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($htmlDoc);

$nodelist = $xpath->query('//*[@id="thisTable"]');

foreach ($nodelist as $n){
    echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

This works, I get the values of the table, but how do I specify the class of a nodeValue? Ultimately, my goal is to build a new table from the `td`'s content of `value2`, `value4` and `value5` in a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$htmlDoc = new DomDocument();
$htmlDoc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($htmlDoc);

$nodelist = $xpath->query('//td');

foreach ($nodelist as $n){
    echo $n->getAttribute("class")."\n";
}
```

**Note**: Use [getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) property for getting values of class

Answer (score 0):

Expand your xpath-query:

```
$class="value1";
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//*[@id="thisTable"][@class="$class"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, if you want the text contents of value2, value4 and value5 in a single row, you can use this xpath:

```
(//td[@class='value2'] | //td[@class='value4'] | //td[@class='value5'])/text()
```

For example:

```
<table id="thisTable"> 
  <tr> 
    <td class="value1">  1111</td>
    <td class="value2"> 222 </td>
    <td class="value3">333 </td> 
    <td class="value4"> 444</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td class="value5">  555</td>
    <td class="value6"> 666</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

output will then be: 222 444 555